# plot word2vec-google-news-300 Gensim

Tags: nlp, gensim

I want to plot the word2vec-google-news-300 words. But I could not find them in the model or download them like this :

```
brew install wget

wget -c "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"
```

or like this :

```
!pip install wget

import wget
url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'
filename = wget.download(url)

f_in = gzip.open('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', 'rb')
f_out = open('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', 'wb')
f_out.writelines(f_in)

import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, KeyedVectors
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True, limit=100000)
```

I want to plot a considerable number to show the beauty of the word embedding. Any help ?

Comment: What error do you get? What source made you think that URL was serving a current copy? Have you tried searching for any other alternative sites also serving that set of vectors? Note that it's hard to make 2D plots (or even 3D plots using perspective or animation) of many 300-dimensional vectors that show much that's meaningful or surprising/insightful. Sometimes, via extreme dimensionality-reduction & selection of the right subset, you can get plots that are interesting, or conform-with/flatter prior understandings of words' neighborhoods.